# stop onload animation loop with button click and find color class of targeted (opacity 1) div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have an onload looping animation of ten divs that fade in and out sequentially with the use of the opacity property. When the user clicks the red button, I want the animation to stop, leaving the div that is at the opacity of 1 to remain at 1 while the others stay at 0.2. Eventually I want another larger div above these to fill with the same color (class) as the one that is at opacity 1. Can anyone give me a hand? I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/seifs4/krm6uenj/20/

Here is my html:

```
    <div id="squares-container">
        <div class="yellow game-square"></div>
        <div class="purple game-square"></div>
        <div class="green game-square"></div>
        <div class="red game-square"></div>
        <div class="blue game-square"></div>
        <div class="yellow game-square"></div>
        <div class="purple game-square"></div>
        <div class="green game-square"></div>
        <div class="red game-square"></div>
        <div class="blue game-square"></div>
    </div><!-- end squares-container -->

    <div id="red-button">Red Button</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#squares-container{
    margin:580px auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#red-button{
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
    background:#CC0000;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fefefe;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    margin:40px 0 0 180px;
    padding:8px 0 0 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.game-square{
    width:65px;
    height:65px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 12px;
    opacity:0.2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 7px 7px #fefefe;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 7px 7px #fefefe;
}
.yellow{
    background:#FFFF00;
}
.green{
    background:#33CC33;
}
.blue{
    background:#3366FF;
}
.purple{
    background:#D617D7;
}
.red{
    background:#F02257;
}
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.extend({
        brighten: function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(150, 1);
        }
    });
    $.fn.extend({
        fade: function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(150, 0.2);
        }
    });

    function animateSequence() {
        $('.game-square').each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay((i++) * 145).brighten();
            $(this).delay((i++) * 5).fade();
        });
    }
    animateSequence()
    setInterval(animateSequence, 1700);

    $('#red-button').click(function(){
        animateSequence().stop();
    });

});
```

Comment: Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/krm6uenj/22/)**??

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I was hoping to have the animation stop and at the precise moment, keep the div that is "lit up" stay lit up, rather than finishing the rest of the animation. Anything like that possible?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if the animation finishes, but is there a way to target the div that has its opacity equal to 1, and tell it to keep its opacity at 1?

Comment: Definitely!! I need some time!! Surely I'll get back with solution!!

Comment: That would be great Guruprasad! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after much effort on this, I could make it 80% work. So just see if that is what you want. Check for the inline comments in below JS

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/krm6uenj/36/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current="";
    $.fn.extend({
        brighten: function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(150, 1);
        }
    });
    $.fn.extend({
        fade: function(){
            $(this).fadeTo(150, 0.2);
        }
    });
    function animateSequence() {
        $('.game-square').each(function (i) {
             $(this).delay((i++) * 145).brighten();
             $(this).delay((i++) * 5).fade();
        });
    }
    animateSequence();
    var interval=setInterval(animateSequence, 1690);
    $('#red-button').on('click',function(){
        clearInterval(interval); //clear the interval
        $('.game-square').each(function(){
            $(this).stop();//stop its delay
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.game-square').each(function(){
                if($(this).css('opacity')>0.3) //get whose opacity was greater which represents current element
                    $(this).css('opacity',1); //Make its opacity 1
             });
        },100);
    });
});
```